# Force Windows to forget DNS server

Tags: windows-7, windows, dns, ipv6

My home network does not support IPv6. If I connect to one that does, and then go home, Windows keeps trying that DNS6 server until it times out. I've tried

```
ipconfig /release6
```

but it doesn't work. Right now I have to open the adapter properties and uncheck/recheck the IPv6 box.

Comment: Wireless or wired? Are you suspending your PC or restarting it? Or neither?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Wireless and suspending. It's my laptop that I carry around to different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've changed networks, Windows should notice instantly whether you have an IPv6 address on the new network. The fact that Windows is still trying to do DNS lookups to an IPv6 DNS server on an IPv4-only network suggests to me that you might have an IPv6 transition technology enabled, such as Teredo, 6to4 or ISATAP. These old technologies were meant to provide IPv6 access over IPv4-only networks, and at this late date are mostly unreliable unless explicitly configured. It's a good idea to ensure that these transition technologies are disabled unless explicitly needed (and it sounds like you don't need them).

Right-click on Command Prompt and choose Run as Administrator. Then paste in the following commands:

```
netsh int ipv6 isatap set state disabled
netsh int ipv6 6to4 set state disabled
netsh int teredo set state disabled
```

You can also disable these with PowerShell (again, as Administrator):

```
Set-NetIsatapConfiguration -State Disabled
Set-Net6to4Configuration -State Disabled
Set-NetTeredoConfiguration -Type Disabled
```

Then restart your computer.

Comment: Yep, I had all of those enabled. I think I might have configured my firewall to silently drop Teredo packets as well. I just disabled those services. I'm on an IPv6 network now so when I get home I'll see if it transitions properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the index :

```
ipconfig /release6 8
```

Where 8 is the index shown by the command:

```
netsh interface ipv6 show interface
```

You may also try the following commands :

```
ipconfig /renew6
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
```

You may also use PowerShell to disable/enable IPv6 of the adapter via :

```
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "Adapter Name" -ComponentID ms_tcpip6
Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "Adapter Name" -ComponentID ms_tcpip6
```

Where the name of the adapter can be found via :

```
Get-NetAdapterBinding -ComponentID ms_tcpip6
```